# Facebook Apps and Cookies

Tags: javascript, fbjs

Do facebook applications written with the help of FBJS need access to cookies? Say for example, my application just gets the the friends of logged in user into an array.

Answer (score 0):

> Do facebook applications written with
>   the help of FBJS need access to
>   cookies? Say for example, my
>   application just gets the the friends
>   of logged in user into an array.

You don't need cookies there. You can store whatever you want into the session (for temporary storage)  or use a database instead. The logical move will be to store users into database in most cases.